Different risk neutral measure
I don't understand in the following example how there can be a single risk neutral measure.
The risk free asset price $B$ at time $t = 1$ is $1+R$.
An other asset $S$ at time $t=1$ can take two values: $d$ with probability $q_d$ and $u$ with probablity $q_u$. We assume that $d \leq u$.
In order to not have arbitrage we must have that the asset can't dominate the risk-free asset and that the risk-free asset can't dominate the asset so:
$$d \leq 1+R \leq u$$
Yet I don't see how this simple inequality forces a single risk-neutral measure $Q$. For example taking $d =1, u =4, R = 1$, then the inequality is respected and we can take whatever probability like for example $q_u = 0.5, q_d = 0.5$ or $q_u = 0.1, q_d = 0.9$.
In my book there are saying this inequality means that the expectation of the asset is equal to $1+R$. But this is not correct right? since I can choose whatever probability measure (as long as both event don't have probability $0$) and my market is arbitrage free.
Even in the more general case (multiple asssets, continuous time...) I don't see how for a market to be arbitrage free a portfolio expectation should always be equal to the risk-free asset. For a market to be arbitrage free we just need that: nothing can completely dominate the risk-free asset (in the sense we can build a portfolio such that with probability $1$ the portfolio value in the future is bigger than the risk-free asset)  or be dominated by the risk-free asset, but with this condition there are a lot of different risk-neutral probability measure that we can find and the expectation will not be equal to the risk free asset.

There are a lot of measures for which the expectation will not be equal to the risk free asset, but you will be able to find ONE where the expectation IS equal to the risk free assset and this measure will be called THE RISK FREE MEASURE.

Another example: if the probabilities of u and d are both 0.5, then you will calculate the forward price of the stock as $(u+d)/2$.  If this is not equal to $1+R$, you will have an arbitrage between the spot and forward price of the stock.

If the discounted asset (call option) is not a martingale then you can hedge it with a martingale (the stock) and earn more/less than the risk free rate, guaranteed.
For example, value an option with the wrong vol (so that it is not a martingale) and you will make the delta hedge consistently gain/lose money.
